# Set value of a private list in visual studio debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

In visual studio you can edit the value of some fields in the locals window or by hovering over them:

[image]

However this doesn't work for replacing a list which is a private field (in this case when I write click on _sectionList the Edit value option is greyed out).

Is there anyway to set the value of a private list field in the visual studio debugger?

In particular I want to replace _sectionList with sectionList2.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT the answers given below might work, but it turned out my field was readonly, so I had to try a different approach anyway.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt, Not very sure that whether you have found a workaround or a solution in your side, but as far as I know readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a variable initializer) and readonly is only enforced at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Immediate Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>) to assign whatever you want to your private fields.

Comment: says `The expression cannot be evaluated while in run mode. `

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Watch 1` tab and let it evaluate the expression `sectionManipulator._sectionList = sectionList2`.